# How can I do a git clone operation using Cake

Tags: c#, git, cakebuild

Is it possible to clone a git repository using a Cake script?  If so, how can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A large number of git operations can be executed using the [Cake.Git Addin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cake.Git/).  Normally, you would be able to find examples on how to use the aliases that are provided by this addin [here](http://cakebuild.net/api/cake.git/8654684f/c158823c), however, these examples do not exist yet.

In the interim, the following shows examples of how each of the four GitClone aliases can be used.

**NOTE:** For the purposes of this answer, we will use the [Cake Git repository](https://github.com/cake-build/cake) on GitHub

#### [GitClone(string, ​DirectoryPath)](http://cakebuild.net/api/cake.git/8654684f/c158823c)​

```
#addin nuget:?package=Cake.Git

Task("Git-Clone")
.Does(() =>
{
    GitClone("https://github.com/cake-build/cake.git", "c:/temp/cake");
});

RunTarget("Git-Clone");
```

#### [GitClone(string, ​DirectoryPath, ​GitCloneSettings)​](http://cakebuild.net/api/cake.git/8654684f/8387b4df)

```
#addin nuget:?package=Cake.Git

Task("Git-Clone")
.Does(() =>
{
    GitClone("https://github.com/cake-build/cake.git", "c:/temp/cake", 
        new GitCloneSettings{ BranchName = "main" });
});

RunTarget("Git-Clone");
```

#### [GitClone(string, ​DirectoryPath, ​string, ​string)​](http://cakebuild.net/api/cake.git/8654684f/b6e993d2)

**NOTE:** This alias doesn't seem to create the output directory.  As a result, the [EnsureDirectoryExists](http://cakebuild.net/api/cake.common.io/11f79db6/bd4d9fa7) alias is used to make sure that it exists.

```
#addin nuget:?package=Cake.Git

Task("Git-Clone")
.Does(() =>
{
    EnsureDirectoryExists("c:/temp/cake");
    GitClone("https://github.com/cake-build/cake.git", 
        "c:/temp/cake", 
        "username", 
        "password");
});

RunTarget("Git-Clone");
```

#### [GitClone(string, ​DirectoryPath, ​string, ​string, ​GitCloneSettings)​](http://cakebuild.net/api/cake.git/cc6863fe)

**NOTE:** This alias doesn't seem to create the output directory.  As a result, the [EnsureDirectoryExists](http://cakebuild.net/api/cake.common.io/11f79db6/bd4d9fa7) alias is used to make sure that it exists.

```
#addin nuget:?package=Cake.Git

Task("Git-Clone")
.Does(() =>
{
    EnsureDirectoryExists("c:/temp/cake");
    GitClone("https://github.com/cake-build/cake.git", 
        "c:/temp/cake", 
        "username", 
        "password", 
        new GitCloneSettings{ BranchName = "main" });
});

RunTarget("Git-Clone");
```